# greater than condition with number and decimal

Tags: javascript

I have a condition that will check if a number is greater than 50,000, if so we show an alert. This works fine, but if you input this 50,000.99 it doesn't trigger the alert, but 51,000.00 does. How do I use a conditional correctly here?

here is my code:

```
if (parseInt(newValue) > 50000.00) {
      toastr.info('Number can not be more than $50000.00');
                        // do something
                    } else {
                        // do something
                    }
```

Comment: `if ( newValue > 50000)` works fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use [`parseInt`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) to parse decimal numbers:

- :( It truncates your numbers
- :( It's unreliable unless you specify a radix
- :( It's slow
- :( It parses non numeric strings if they begin with a number

Instead, you could use [`parseFloat`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.3). But wait:

- :) It does not truncate your numbers
- :) There is no radix problem
- :( It's slow
- :( It parses non numeric strings if they begin with a number

There is a better approach: the [unary `+` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6):

- :) It does not truncate your numbers
- :) There is no radix problem
- :) It's so fast
- :) It does not parse non completely numeric strings

But wait: when you use the greater-than Operator `>`, the operands are automatically converted to numbers (unless both are strings).

So just use

```
newValue > 50000
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use parsint. It converts your string/number to an integer, effectively lopping off the decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseFloat`, not `parseInt`, if you want a number with a fraction. Integers don't have fractions. Real numbers have fractions, and they're represented in computer programs as floating point.

Comment: no reason to insult me there, I don't remember taking Javascript in grade school math. Matter of fact, when I was in grade school, the first computer wasn't invented yet

Comment: That has nothing to do with Javascript or computers. The ancient Greeks knew the difference between integers and fractions.

Comment: So the parseInt() and parseFloat() functions are not javascript, but part of ancient greek math?

Comment: No, but the abbreviation `Int` is clearly short for `integer`. So if you know what an integer is, then it should be obvious that it doesn't return numbers with fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Use parseFloat:

```
if (parseFloat(newValue) > 50000.00) {
      toastr.info('Number can not be more than $50000.00');
      // do something
 } else {
      // do something
 }
```

The [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function parses a string argument and returns a floating point number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Works a it should now

Answer (score 1):

Use parseFloat instead of parseInt when working with decimal values.

```
parseInt("234")//234
parseInt("234.551")//234
parseInt(".234")//NaN

parseFloat("234")//234
parseFloat("234.551")//234.551
parseFloat(".234")//0.234

+("234")//234
+("234.551")//234.551
+(".234")//0.234
```